ResolvePackageNotFound message due to the channel constraints
I was trying to reproduce a developing environment using a given yml file, such as
conda env create -f "C:\tmp\proj_dev.yml"

Due to some security constraints, I have to using a given channel instead of generic "conda-forge" or "anaconda" channel. However, running the above command gives me errors such as
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - ca-certificates==2023.08.22=haa95532_0

My understanding is that the original development environment uses this package associated with this specific version. However, the assigned channel does not have this package along with this version. The "ResolvePackageNotFound" message lists more than 60 packages. Are there any solutions to resolve this kind of scenario. Thanks.

I think the only solution is to edit the YAML file and delete everything after (and including) the first ==, for all the packages that aren't found. That will remove the version constraints and, assuming some compatible version of the packages are available, will find them
